# Sharing styles throught oracle

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial

I'm connecting to Oracle database with QGIS.

Is there a way to load default styles for layer not from user's schema ?
Even though user can access QGIS.LAYER_STYLES table (schema name - QGIS), QGIS checks if user has table named LAYER_STYLES and doesn't even try to query LAYER_STYLES table (which would succeed).

From what I understand I would have to create a LAYER_STYLES table for every user seperately and update them all each time. I'd rather every user getting styles from unspecified schema by QGIS(from LAYER_STYLES) - whatever Oracle decides to give them.

Am I missing something ? **Whats a good way to share styles inside an organisation with oracle database, only LDF / Project files ?**

Check query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tables WHERE table_name='LAYER_STYLES'`
Qgis version: 3.28.15-Firenze